# How to iterate over a nested collection within a Map in Freemarker?

Tags: java, freemarker

I would like to iterate over a nested collection within a Map in Freemarker 2.3.15.

I pass the following to the view:

```
Map<ApplicationPropertyDefinition, Collection<ApplicationProperty>> = getValues();
```

I have attempted the following:

```
<#if propertiesByDefinition?size gt 0>
<#list propertiesByDefinition?keys as definition>
    <strong>${definition.externalReference!''}</strong>

    <#list propertiesByDefinition?values as value>
        ${value.name}
    </#list>

</#list>
</#if>
```

Error:

```
Expected hash. value evaluated instead to freemarker.template.SimpleSequence on line 65, column 19 in templates/propertygroup/values.txt.
The problematic instruction:
----------
==> ${value.name} escaped ${(value.name!"")?html} [on line 65, column 17 in templates/propertygroup/values.txt]
----------
```

How do I correctly iterate over the nested Collection so I can access the String value "name" in each of the ApplicationProperty objects?

Answer (score 1):

You have to retrieve a `Collection` object for the given `definition`

Try this:

```
<#if propertiesByDefinition?size gt 0>
    <#list propertiesByDefinition?keys as definition >
        <strong>${definition.externalReference!''}</strong>

        <#list propertiesByDefinition.get(definition) as value>
            ${value.name}
        </#list>

    </#list>
</#if>
```

And here with some code improvement:

```
<#if propertiesByDefinition?has_content >
    <#list propertiesByDefinition as definition, collection >
        <strong>${definition.externalReference!''}</strong>

        <#list collection as value >
            ${value.name}
        </#list>

    </#list>
</#if>
```

Here I'm using `#list` key-value pairs of a map available since Freemarker 2.3.25...

```
<#list map as key, value>
    ${key} : ${value}
</#list>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a method that takes the `ApplicationPropertyDefinition` as a parameter and return the collection found for that parameter.

```
public Collection<ApplicationProperty> getPropertiesForDefinition(ApplicationPropertyDefinition definition) {
    return propertiesByDefinition.get(definition)
}
```

Which would result in:

```
<#list propertiesByDefinition?keys as definition>
    <strong>${definition.externalReference!''}</strong>

    <#list getPropertiesByDefinition(definition) as value>
        ${value.name}
    </#list>
</#list>
```